# Flex programming

Tags: image, apache-flex, nas

I am trying load images dynamically from my NAS but when I defined the source as

> //myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg

the image could not be shown. If I changed the source as c:/myPath/myImage.jpg it worked. Below is the code. I have tried the following source from NAS but none of them worked:

1. //myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg
2. ///myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg
3. ////myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg
4. \\myNASDriveName\myPath/myImage.jpg

   ```
   <mx:Panel title="Image Example" width="600">
     <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
       <mx:Label text="BitmapImage loaded at runtime"/>
       <mx:Image id="runtimeimg" source="//myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg"/>
     </mx:VBox>
   </mx:Panel>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
file://myNASDriveName/myPath/myImage.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have tried putting file: at the front but still not working.

Comment: I've tried it out on a local project it worked on my network drive.